# PyTorch normalize two sets of gradients during training

Tags: pytorch, normalization

In this [GAN tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html), if you scroll down to the training loop you can see they combine the gradients 
 `errD = errD_real + errD_fake` like this. Where `errD_real = criterion(output, label)` and `errD_fake = criterion(output, label)` and `criterion = nn.BCELoss()`. I want to do the same thing but before doing a backward pass I want to normalize both gradients to the lower Euclidean norm of the two. How would I do that?

I know I can access the gradients of each weight individually on netD by printing out `netD.weight.grad`, but is there some way to batchnorm them to the lower Euclidean norm of the two?

Here's the part of the training loop I'm talking about:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # For each batch in the dataloader
    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):

        ############################
        # (1) Update D network: maximize log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
        ###########################
        ## Train with all-real batch
        netD.zero_grad()
        # Format batch
        real_cpu = data[0].to(device)
        b_size = real_cpu.size(0)
        label = torch.full((b_size,), real_label, device=device)
        # Forward pass real batch through D
        output = netD(real_cpu).view(-1)
        # Calculate loss on all-real batch
        errD_real = criterion(output, label)
        # Calculate gradients for D in backward pass
        errD_real.backward()
        D_x = output.mean().item()

        ## Train with all-fake batch
        # Generate batch of latent vectors
        noise = torch.randn(b_size, nz, 1, 1, device=device)
        # Generate fake image batch with G
        fake = netG(noise)
        label.fill_(fake_label)
        # Classify all fake batch with D
        output = netD(fake.detach()).view(-1)
        # Calculate D's loss on the all-fake batch
        errD_fake = criterion(output, label)
        # Calculate the gradients for this batch
        errD_fake.backward()
        D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
        # Add the gradients from the all-real and all-fake batches
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        # Update D
        optimizerD.step()
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned two things which are incorrect.

1. `errD = errD_real + errD_fake` basically combines two objective function, not gradients.
2. You need to change the gradients after the backward pass, not before. With the backward pass, the gradients will be computed and then you can modify the gradients before calling `optimizer.step()` which updates the model parameters.

Answer to your question:

I believe there is no direct API support from PyTorch to achieve your goal. However, you can easily modify the gradients by yourself after the backward pass. To compute the Euclidean norm, you can use the [norm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=norm#torch.norm) function. Then you can simply [divide](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=div_#torch.Tensor.div_) the gradients (inplace).

Comment: Ok, do I just loop through all of the gradients to do the inplace calculations?

Comment: yes, you need to loop through all the parameters of the model. Use `model.named_parameters()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You better leave the gradients intact and make your optimizer so that it will count the effects you need.

Gradients will in most cases be deleted before a new forward anyway.

Some newer algorithms such as [Lamb](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00962) do the trick of parameter-wise (layer-wise) gradient normalization (MSE in this case) like you plan.

Also, check the [SAGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.08318) paper and why they used `nn.utils.spectral_norm` since you mantioned GANs.

Comment: Thanks this is useful, however, in my case I'm more worried about a situation where I have two simultaneous loss updates and one is essentially overpowering the other. I think the cases you post here are more about training optimization yea? I just want to make sure the two gradient updates have equal impact on my optimizer step

Comment: Yes, think of gradients like food that is already prepared so you don't need to prepare it anymore, and the optimizer is what you do with it, or guts.